# write each line of a list into different text files and save it with different names

Tags: python-3.x

i have an appended list and i want to write each line from the list into different text files and save the files with different names.

The relevant part of my code is:

```
        #append new values to list
        tl1.append(tl1)
        br1.append(br1)
        label1.append(label1)

        res.append(((label1, tl1, br1)))

        #write list to text file
        with open('Result.txt', 'w') as f:
            for items in res:
                f.write("{}\n".format(items))
```

Assume variables and other parameters have already ben defined.
So here my entire list is saved into one file But i want each value of res to be stored in different text files and each text file should be saved with different name . eg. the first value of the list should be saved into a text file and this file should be called frame001.txt, second value should be saved in a different text file and this should be called frame002.txt, third value should be stored into a different file and this should be called frames003.txt and so on. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to write to a file so your question is mainly about dynamically creating filenames based on the current iteration index:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
for index, item in enumerate(lst, 1):
     print("frame{:03d}.txt".format(index))
```

I leave it up to you to read the FineManual for those functions.

EDIT:

> This creates filenames equal to the number of indexes in the list. How do i pass the value of the list to the respective files?

You're already doing it in your original snippet.

> This also prints the filenames. Does not create dynamic files

How do you create "Result.txt" in your original code ? FWIW, "dynamic files" doesn't mean anything - you create a file by opening it in write mode, quite simply.

As I said, given your original snippet, you already know how to do those things, so I don't see a need for explaining it again. I understand you might be a beginner but solving the remaining part of the puzzle is only question of logic, and a very simple one actually - even for a beginner.

Comment: This creates filenames equal to the number of indexes in the list. How do i pass the value of the list to the respective files? This also prints the filenames. Does not create dynamic files